# Hadoop Quirky Behavior

Tags: hadoop

Is it possible that datanode doesn't start sometimes on running start-all.sh but when you restart the computer it starts fine. What could be a cause of such a quirky behavior?

Do other java processes running within the same namespace corrupt the hadoop processes?

Comment: Turn on verbose logging in the data node and check for any exceptions. There might be tons of reason why something doesn't work. Without proper information, it's difficult to diagnose a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the things I observed.

1. hadoop namenode -format. This command needs to be executed before you start-all. Otherwise  namenode doesn't start.
2. Also check that the application you are using on top of hadoop complies with the version of hadoop that the application expects. In my case I was using hadoop 20.203 and I switched to 20.2 my problem was solved.
3. Check the logs, they often give valuable insights into what has gone wrong.